# Unable to load thumbnails into ListView

Tags: android, listview, gallery

I am currently attempting to make a simple image gallery like the now deprecated Android `Gallery`. From this gallery the user can also navigate to a simple image editor by selecting an image form the gallery. After a lot of Googling I managed to find a `HorizontalListView` [here](http://www.dev-smart.com/?p=34) which is exactly what I need. Initially I had a lot of success with this by just inserting the images in my folder as compressed bitmaps. Since then however I have found [this video from Google I/O](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gbQb1PVjfqM&list=PL46069800A957F535&index=10) in which they create an image gallery and an image editor; similar to what I am attempting to create. There are however two main differences between my app and theirs:

- they use a `GridView` for their gallery and I use the aforementioned `HorizontalListView`
- I am attempting to only load images from a specified target path rather than just all images on the SD card.

So far I am unable to adapt their code to mine as none of the images are loading into my gallery. As with the video I use an AsyncTask to load my thumbnails:

```
    private class ThumbnailAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Long, Void, Bitmap>
    {
        //The ImageView we will be adding the thumbnail to
        private final ImageView mTarget;

        public ThumbnailAsyncTask(ImageView target)
        {
            mTarget = target;
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Long... params) 
        {
            final long photoID = params[0];

            final Bitmap result = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                    getContentResolver(), photoID, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, null);

            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            mTarget.setTag(this);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result)
        {
            if (mTarget.getTag() == this) 
            {
                mTarget.setImageBitmap(result);
                mTarget.setTag(null);
            }
        }   
}
```

and I am using a CursorAdapter for the images in the gallery:

```
   private class PhotoAdapter extends CursorAdapter
   {
    public PhotoAdapter(Context context)
    {
        super(context, null, false);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) 
    {
        final long photoId = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID));

        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.icon);

        /* 
         * Cancel any pending thumbnail task, since this view is now bound
         * to new thumbnail
         */
        final ThumbnailAsyncTask oldTask = (ThumbnailAsyncTask) imageView.getTag();

        if (oldTask != null) 
            oldTask.cancel(false);    

        /* 
         * If we arrived here, either cache is disabled or cache miss, so we
         * need to kick task to load manually
         */
        final ThumbnailAsyncTask task = new ThumbnailAsyncTask(imageView);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
        imageView.setTag(task);
        task.execute(photoId);
    }
}
```

With the following CursorLoader

```
    final LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> mCursorCallbacks = new LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>() 
            {
                @Override
                public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) 
                {
                    final String[] columns = {BaseColumns._ID};
                    return new CursorLoader(NewProjectActivity.this,
                            Uri.fromFile(new File(mTargetPath)), columns, null, null,
                            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED + " DESC");
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) 
                {
                    mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) 
                {
                    mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
                }
            };

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_CURSOR, null, mCursorCallbacks);
```

Any ideas on why none of my images are loading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic problem here is, `bindView()` method is not waiting for asynctask's result. You need to notify your list view when some of its content get changed.

You can do the following changes.

1) Change `task.execute(photoId);` to `task.execute(photoId).get();` this will force your `bindView()` method to wait till you get your image. This approach is not advisable but it will help you to understand the exact problem.

**OR**

2) In `onPost()` of `asynctask`, invalidate your list view's old content and try to reload it with new content.

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
mAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
```

**OR**

3) Personally i will suggest you to finish all network operation first (i.e. fetching images ) by changing your code structure and then after try to set your adapter with the prefetched data. This is not a perfect solution but it worked in my case.

Comment: I tried your first suggestion without any success so how would I got about implementing your second suggestion? Would I simply call `notifyDataSetChanged()`? I apologize as I am something of an Android newbie.

Comment: I just ended up re-organising my code as you suggested and finally got it working. Thanks :)